# Salvar no banco de dados ou gerar nova página html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

To fazendo um portal de noticias. 
O administrador vai alimentar o sistema por meio de um painel administrativo.  To trabalhando com php e mysql.
A questão é: gerar um arquivo html pra cada nova notícia? Ou salvar tudo no banco de dados? 
Os dois métodos funcionam, más qual o melhor?

Comment: Cara recomendo vc salvar no banco.. conforme o sistema crescer fica melhor para dar manutenção é fica um trampo mais dinâmico..

Comment: Gerar um arquivo html pra cada nova notícia é loucura.

Answer (score 3):

Sem dúvida alguma, você deve armazenar as notícias em um banco de dados.

Criar uma página pra cada notícia é completamente inviável. Isso só funciona em sites de conteúdo statico, que não mudam.

Pense nos seguintes pontos:

- Você precisará editar as notícias, seja pra corrigir ou adicionar informações
- Você precisará incluir anúncios, mesmo que não agora, para monetizar seu portal
- Você precisará, com o tempo, mudar o layout do seu portal
- Você precisará ter controle de informações de estatisticas, ferramentas de monitoramento e controle dos usuários. Tudo isso se faz com programação do lado do servidor, você não quer fazer tudo isso sempre que lançar uma nova notícia, não é?
- As vezes é necessário um sistema de comentários

Tem muitos outros pontos que daria pra citar, são infinitas as vantagens de se usar o banco de dados.

A única vantagem de usar arquivos HTML que eu consigo enxergar, seria o ganho de performance, que nem vai ser tão  grande assim se o seu portal for pequeno, com poucos acessos. Mas, isso você pode contornar de maneira bem simples usando o PHP pra criar algum sistema de cache e isso vai de acordo com suas necessidades. Na maioria dos casos, não será necessário.

Um exemplo de sistema de cache simples e eficiente é criar uma tabela no banco de dados e nela armazenar todos os valores necessário para montar determinada página. Você ainda precisará consultar o banco de dados pra obter esses valores, mas invés de fazer por exemplo cinco consultas SQL, você irá fazer apenas uma consulta. Você só irá fazer as cinco consultas pra montar a página uma vez por dia ou quando o dono do sistema atualizar alguma informação na página em questão e nesse momento você cria o seu cache que será utilizado nas demais visitas.

Comment: A melhor resposta até aqui.